# как установить slackware в режиме uefi

Tags: linux, uefi, slackware

расскажите подробнее, пожалуйста. а то не разобраться в английских статьях...

Comment: [тогда попробуйте разобраться в статье на русском](http://wiki.slackware.su/wiki:od:uefi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Берете дистрибутив Slackware64
2. Делаете установочный носитель
3. Грузите машину в режиме EFI с установочного носителя
4. Ставите
5. Пользуетесь

С каким из шагов возникли трудности/непонятки?